# php exec shell command with regexp matching

Tags: php, regex, exec

I'm creating small algorithm to fix msgid entire source code so this working ok:

```
$ find . -name '*.php' | xargs perl -pi -e 's/\$t\(\047bad msgid\047\);/\$t\(\047good msg id\047\);/g'
```

I want to create execute inside foreach of php script eg:

```
$cmd = "find {$projectPath} -name '*.php' | xargs perl -pi -e 's/\$t\('\047'" . preg_quote($bad) . "\047\)/\$t\(\047" . preg_quote($good) . "\047\)/g'";
exec(escapeshellarg($cmd));
```

Its crazy i try everything, escapeshellarg, mix doubled quotes with single quotes, backslash quotes.. after 4h i can tell one fu*ck this and shell exec cmd. ps. fuc*k reg exp too

any idea to run this command inside exec method ?

---

**Solution** for find $t('misspel msgid') replace to $t('right msgid') inside entire project usind php, perl, exec (tested on mac)

+1h and 2rev, thanks for suggestion @Marc B:

```
$cmd = "find {$projectPath} -name '*.php' | xargs perl -pi -e 's|\\\$t\(\\047" . str_replace("'", "\\047", preg_quote($bad)) . "\\047\)|\\\$t\(\\047" . str_replace("'", "\\047", preg_quote($good)) . "\\047\)|g'";
exec($cmd);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A basic understanding of quoting would help...

The `\` you have in your $cmd string defnitition are consumed by PHP.

`escapeshallarg()` only deals with quotes, so your `$t` in the xargs get passed through verbatim to the shell, so you end doing essentially the equivalent of having typed the following at the shell prompt:

```
$ find /project/path -name '*.php' | xargs .... 's/$t etc....'
```

The `$t` will get expanded by the shell, and since you don't have a `$t` defined in this new shell, your regexes turn into

```
's/('\047
   ^---hey, no $t value!
```

Try

```
$cmd = "find {$projectPath} -name '*.php' | blah blah s/\\$t etc...
                                                        ^^--double escape
```

One backslash will be consumed by PHP, leaving `s/\$t` in the string. When that gets pased to the shell, the `\$t` will get passed in to perl as `$t` and be treated as a perl variable...

Comment: when i push double \\$t php try take $t as varsible so i push \\\$t and it produce better string but still not working